# How to get file list using system variable %LOCALAPPDATA%?

Tags: c#, file, directory, system-variable

I want to read the content of the folder located at %LOCALAPPDATA%. But it fails when I tried

```
Directory.GetDirectories("%LOCALAPPDATA%");
```

I get "The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context"
Please help.

Answer (score 5):

[Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)